# Is Right hand, left hand, and middle riemann sum formula the same?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

Are the right hand, left hand, and middle Riemann sum formulas for $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ the same?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\Delta x,$$ where $\Delta x =\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i=a+i\Delta x$.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the formulas are not the same, but they are similar.  Consider an interval $[a,b]$ and a partition of the interval $a = x_{1} < x_{2} < \dotsb < x_{n} = b$, where $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$ is the spacing between points.  Then the formulas for the Riemann sums will change, depending on which point (right/left/middle) in the subinterval is chosen:
\begin{align}
\text{Right:}\quad \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=2}^{n}f(x_{i})\Delta x\\
\text{Left:}\quad \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_{i})\Delta x\\
\text{Middle:}\quad \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f\left(\frac{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}{2}\right)\Delta x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=2}^{n}f\left(\frac{x_{i}-x_{i-1}}{2}\right)\Delta x
\end{align}

It is easiest to see why this is the case if you sketch out a graph and label some points.  You should be able to see why the indices on the sums change depending on whether you pick the right or left point on each sub-interval.

Comment: Ok thanks. But for calculate $\Delta x$ and $x_i$ it's the same?

Comment: Yes, the partition doesn't change, just which of those points you use.

Comment: My professor has shown right: = summation from i=1, rather than i=2. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Rohin it entirely depends on how you label the partition.  If you name the points $a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsb < x_n = b$ then yes the sum would go from $i = 1$ instead of $i = 2$.  Since I used $a = x_1 < x_2 < \dotsb < x_n = b$ then the first interval was $(x_1,x_2)$ and I started the sum with the right index, $i = 2$, but if your first interval were $(x_0,x_1)$ then your first right index would be $i = 1$, but it entirely depends on how you name your indices.

Comment: got it, thanks !